# Automatic web page forwarding

Tags: html, jsp, web-applications, https, meta-tags

my registration page (**empregistration.jsp**)is automatically forwarding to (**success.jsp**) how to stop this I just want to forward it when i press submit button

> empregistration.jsp

```
<%@ page language ="java" contentType ="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding ="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %> 
 <html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="30;URL=emplogin.action">
       <sx:head/>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src ="script.js"></script>

    </head>  

      <body>
        <div align="center"> <h1 style="color: red">  ENPLOYEE REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
       <s:form  action="emplogin"  method="post" >

      <s:textfield name="firstname" label="Employee Firstname"/>
      <s:textfield name ="lastname" label ="Last name"/>  
      <s:textfield name ="id"  label="Id"/>
      <s:radio name ="gender"   list="{'male', 'female'}" label = "Gender"/>
    <sx:datetimepicker name="dob" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy"  label="DOB"></sx:datetimepicker> 
      <s:radio  name ="maritalstatus" list="{'singale','married'}" label="Marital Status" />

      <s:textfield name ="email" label ="Email"/>
 <sx:datetimepicker name ="joiningdate" displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" label="Joining Date"></sx:datetimepicker>

      <s:textfield name= "designation" label = "Designation"/>
      <s:textarea name ="address" label ="Address" />
      <s:textfield name = "country" label ="Country" />     
      <s:textfield name  ="state" label = "State" />
      <s:textfield name  ="city" label ="City"/> 
      <s:textfield name ="pincode" label ="Pincode"/>
      <s:textfield name ="mobileno" label="Mobile No"/>
      <s:select   name ="groups" list="{'group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'}"  label ="Group"  cssStyle="{width:184px"/>
     <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <s:submit align="center"></s:submit>
      </s:form>
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Remove `<script type="text/javascript"  src ="script.js"></script>`

Comment: @Mayurb, put that as an answer... and Arvind, how on earth can you put a tag like that without knowing what it does and then ask why it act that way ? :/ Or is somebody else's code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="30;URL=emplogin.action">`
This tag in your `empregistration.jsp` will refresh the page.

May be this is the problem in your code.In meta tag you have specified the URL as `empLogin.action`.When the page refresh it automatically invoke `emplogin.action` and redirects you to `success.jsp`.
Remove this tag from your jsp.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

remove it from your page it will work .

Answer (score -2):

in your empregistration.jsp page there is one script, may be its createn your problem

but now day submit button is not proper way to submit your detail in form.

you can put one anchor tag in place of submit button

here code is:

```
   <a onclick="emplogin()">Login</a>
```

and put javascript in head part::

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function emplogin()
         {
             document.getElementById('myform').submit();
          }
    </script>
```

and set one id="myform" to your form like:

```
   <form id="myform">
   </form>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? What's wrong with a submit button being used to submit a form?!

Comment: I am asking about Java Script's functions that's not my question.